# Rails4: Unpermitted parameter with using nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, fields-for

`Unpermitted parameter` is displayed when I try to create new data.
Althogh there are many similar questions, I can't find out how to solve.

What I'd like to do is to save the value in the `amounts` table when create `schedule`.

**log**

```
Processing by SchedulesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "schedule"=>{"title"=>"test title", "departure_date"=>"2016-07-06", "rooms_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"schedule_id"=>"", "amounts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"schedule_id"=>"", "room_id"=>""}}}}}, "commit"=>"Create my schedule"}
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "schedule"=>{"title"=>"test title", "departure_date"=>"2016-07-06", "rooms_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"schedule_id"=>"", "amounts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"schedule_id"=>"", "room_id"=>""}}}}}, "commit"=>"Create my schedule"}
  User Load (120.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (120.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: amounts_attributes
```

**models**

schedule.rb

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :rooms, inverse_of: :schedule, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :amounts, inverse_of: :schedule, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :amounts, allow_destroy: true
```

rooms.rb

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :schedule, inverse_of: :rooms
  has_many :events, inverse_of: :room, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :amounts, inverse_of: :room, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :amounts, allow_destroy: true
```

amount.rb

```
class Amount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :schedule, inverse_of: :amounts
  belongs_to :room, inverse_of: :amounts
  belongs_to :event, inverse_of: :amounts
end
```

**controller**

schedule_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @schedule = Schedule.new
    room = @schedule.rooms.build
    room.amounts.build
  end

  def create
    @schedule = current_user.schedules.build(schedule_params)
    if @schedule.save
      flash[:success] = "schedule created!"
      redirect_to schedule_path(@schedule)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

...

  def schedule_params
    params.require(:schedule).permit(
      :title, :departure_date, 
      rooms_attributes: [
        :id, :_destroy, :room, :room_address, :schedule_id, :day,  
        amounts_attributes: [
          :schedule_id, :room_id, :event_id, :id, :_destroy, :ccy, :amount
        ]
      ]
    )
  end
```

**view**

/schedules/new.html.erb

```
...
<%= form_for(@schedule) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'schedule_form', f: f %>
  <%= f.submit "Create my schedule", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
...
```

/schedules/ _schedule_form.html.erb

It works before adding 4 lines for `<%= room.fields_for(:amounts) do |amount| %>`.

```
...
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
...

<%= f.fields_for(:rooms) do |room| %>
  <%= room.hidden_field :schedule_id %>

  <%= room.fields_for(:amounts) do |amount| %> # my app works before add these 4 lines.
    <%= amount.hidden_field :schedule_id %>    #
    <%= amount.hidden_field :room_id %>        #
  <% end %>                                    #

<% end %>
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.

Comment: You dont have a :schedule_id in your strong params for amounts_attributes, but you pass it as a param

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @hypern. I failed to copy & paste. I update strong parameter in `schedule_controller.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the room_attributes array parameter.Please close it and open the amount's attribute nested parameters. Also the schedule_id in amount's attributes.

```
def schedule_params
        params.require(:schedule).permit(:title, 
        :departure_date,{rooms_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :room, :room_address, :schedule_id, :day,
        { amounts_attributes: [:itinerary_id, :room_id, :event_id, :id, :_destroy, :ccy, :amount]}
        ]}
        )
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Sravan. Although I tried your answer, the following error is displayed. `SyntaxError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/controllers/schedules_controller.rb:83: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting ')'`

Comment: is your problem solved now? Actually I mis understood the quetion. Now I am changing the answer

Comment: No, it doesn't solve. I still have the same error `Unpermitted parameter: amounts_attributes`.

Comment: I updated the answer please check, it it does not work, then the error should be either in the asscsciations or in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Following from the logged params, your `amounts_attributes` is an array of objects and should be declared as such in your `permit` method argument:

```
def schedule_params
    params.require(:schedule).permit(
      :title, :departure_date, 
      rooms_attributes: [{
        :id, :_destroy, :room, :room_address, :schedule_id, :day,  
        amounts_attributes: [{
          :itinerary_id, :room_id, :event_id, :id, :_destroy, :ccy, :amount
        }]
      }]
    )
end
```

The `rooms_attributes` follows similar structure and needs to be corrected as well.

Take a look at the nested parameters example in [ActionController::Parameters docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Nic Nilov.  The syntax error was displayed when I add curly bracket.

Answer (score 0):

I think your params should look like this:

```
def schedule_params
    params.require(:schedule).permit(
      :title, :departure_date, 
      rooms_attributes: [
        :id, :_destroy, :room, :room_address, :schedule_id, :day,  
        amounts_attributes: [ :id, :_destroy,
          :itinerary_id, :room_id, :event_id, :id, :_destroy, :ccy, :amount]
]
)
end
```

So, for your nested model, even if it's deeply nested, you still need :id and :_destroy.

Let me know how that goes for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @nilatti. When I changed the `amounts_attributes` as follwoings, `Unpermitted parameter` is disappeard. `amounts_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :itinerary_id, :room_id, :event_id,  :ccy, :amount]`. I already have `:id, :_destroy,` in the `amounts_attributes`. So I changed the position of these two. But `itinerary_id` hasn't saved yet. Do you have any thought?

Comment: This might sound kind of silly, but I don't see where in your form you are setting an itinerary.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @nilatti. I'm sorry I made typo. I changed `itinerary_id` to `schedule_id` in the `amounts_attributes`. Although `schedule_id` is also used in the `rooms_attributes`, it can be saved in the rooms table.